# What is the correct way to scan "Quoted String" in ragel?

Tags: ragel

I m trying learn ragel with go, but i am not able to find a proper way to scan a Quoted-string

This is what i have defined

```
dquote      = '"';
quoted_string = dquote (any*?) dquote ;

main := |*
    quoted_string =>
            {
                current_token = QUOTED_STRING;
                yylval.stringValue = string(lex.m_unScannedData[lex.m_ts:lex.m_te]);
                fmt.Println("quoted string : ", yylval.stringValue)
                fbreak;
            };
```

The following expression with single quoted string works fine

```
if abc == "xyz.123" {
        pp
}
```

If i scan the above condition then i get this printf

> quoted string :  "xyz.123"

But if i have 2 quoted string as shown below, it fails

```
if abc == "0003" {
        if xyz == "5003" {
                pp
        }
}
```

it scans both the quoted string

> quoted string :  "0003" {
>           if xyz == "5003"

Can someone please help me with this ? If there is a better alternative

I am using below version

```
# ragel -v
Ragel State Machine Compiler version 6.10 March 2017
Copyright (c) 2001-2009 by Adrian Thurston
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
quoted_string = dquote (any - newline)* dquote ;
```